# Javascript, toggle display of two divs based on foreach on JSON object

Tags: javascript

The basic thing I'm trying to do here is iterate through this JSON object containing 2 records (always only 2 records) and getting the value, which is a URL. Then setting the src of two divs to each of those URLS (which then creates two divs on the page that embed a PDF file), and finally toggling the display of each so that at any given time one of the embeds is display:block and one is display:none (only one embed should show at any given time, and they should cycle every 60 seconds.

The issues I have right now:

- Setting the URL of each object as the src of each div
- properly toggling the display of the divs, only setting each to hidden currently

How can I change my forEach here in order to properly toggle the displays of the embed sections, and how would I properly set the src of each embed with the corresponding URL value from the object?

```
@section('content')

<embed class="pdf" src="https://test.s3.aws/test1.pdf#zoom=85&view=Fit&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&navpanes=0 " style="margin-top: 40px;position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0;" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">

<embed class="pdf" src="https://test.s3.aws/test2.pdf#zoom=85&view=Fit&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&navpanes=0 " style="margin-top: 40px;position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; display:none" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf">



@endsection

@section('loadjs')

<script>

var files = {"1":"https://test.s3.aws/test1.pdf",
             "2":"https://test.s3.aws/test2.pdf"}
;
const result = JSON.parse(files);

Object.entries(result).forEach((entry) => {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);

    //need to get the URL, which is value here, into the src of each div
})

const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('pdf');

for(let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        divs[i].style.display = none;
    }, i * 60000)
  }

//toggle display:none for each embed with a 60second timer

</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1):

Build the element you need with javascript

```
Function myEmbeds (opt) { 

let p = document.createElement("embed")
p.height = window.innerHeight
p.source = files[opt] // the url
p.type = "application/pdf"
p.width = window.innerWidth
return p
}
setTimeout(() => {
        document.appendChild(myEmbeds(1)) //i is even etc...
    }, i * 60000)
```

Comment: I think this makes sense to me for the most part, but how would I append the argments after the url starting with the ```#zoom```?

Comment: Modify the `source` parameter of the element. Maybe define a string constant from your files object `const partOfSource = files[0] + '#zoom'; `. Also,   Sorry I didn't get the appendChild() finished in the answer but that's just iterations on 1 or 0